# How would I randomly choose changing variables that meet conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
a = 3;
b = 3;
c = 3;
turnCount = 1;
function decrease(x, y) //x represents a, b, c while y subtracts 1, 2, or 3//
    //stuff I figured out//
```

So I'm trying to create an AI for a game, where there are 3 turns. TurnCount 1 and 2 are the computer and 3 is the player turn. On the computer turn, they will always subtract 1 from the variable with the highest value. There are 9 buttons that subtract 1, 2, or 3 from each variable. Any button that would subtract more than the value in the variable will be disabled. Now, my problem is that I want to randomize which variable is subtracted from if there is more than one variable with the highest value. My approach was this:

```
function theAI()
{
    highestValue = Math.max(a, b, c);
    theArray = ["", a, b, c];
    varToDecrease = theArray.indexOf(highestValue);
    decrease(varToDecrease, 1);
}
```

However this approach will always make a and b equal 2, therefore the buttons to subtract 3 from the variables will never be used. Can anyone please help think of a way to randomize which highestValue variable is subtracted from, so that the subtract 3 buttons are allowed to work for all three variables?

Comment: Can you use Math.random()?

Comment: you could use javascript to find all the instances - example here on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf then math random over that array of indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find all the indexes of your max value, then use math random to choose an element from the array.

```
function theAI()
{
    highestValue = Math.max(a, b, c);
    theArray = ["", a, b, c];
    var idx = array.indexOf(element);
    while (idx != -1) {
      indices.push(idx);
      idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
    }
    varToDecrease = indices[Math.floor(indices.length * Math.random())];
    decrease(varToDecrease, 1);
}
```

I'm using a while loop here to search for each instance of the highest value in the array.  (It is actually close to a do-while syntax)

First I set the idx to the first location of the highest element in the array. Since I found the max element with Math.max, there is not possible that this will ever not be found.  So when something is found with indexOf, it returns the index, when something is not found, it returns -1.

So it will enter the while loop, add the current location of the highest element to the array, and then set idx to the next index of the highest element.  If there is only one found int the array, it will return -1, and the while loop will end.  However, if the idx is not -1, that means there is another max element int he array, and so the while loop will loop again.

Comment: I  think I understand your code, but can you explain the while part?

Comment: Absolutely! Updated.